Mocking PySpark in unit tests
I have a python method along the lines of this:
def my_big_method():
    # stuff happens before this

    df = (
        spark.read
        .format("jdbc")
        .option("url", f"jdbc:postgresql://{host}:{port}/{database}")
        .option("query", query)
        .option("user", username)
        .option("password", password)
        .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
        .load()
    )

    # stuff happens after this

    return df

I'm having trouble mocking the spark session. Basically I want that in the unit test of this method, df is s predetermined data frame like this:
spark.createDataFrame([(1, "Alice"), (2, "Bob")]

How would I go about doing that? Which method is the one I have to patch? I have tried:
patch("pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate")
patch("pyspark.sql.SparkSession")

And in both cases, spark tries to make a call to the DB in the unit test.

Is it possible to change the code? I see here 2 possible solutions:

Change your loading code to spark.read.jdbc(**conn_params) and mock pyspark.sql.readwriter.DataFrameReader's jdbc method to return the necessary dataframe.

Create a helper function and mock it.


# module_with_code.py
def read_from_db(spark_session, **conn_params):
    return spark_session.read.jdbc(**conn_params)

# conftest.py
import module_with_code

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mock_read_from_db(monkeypatch):
    def inner(session, **kwargs):
        return session.createDataFrame([(1, "Alice"), (2, "Bob")]
    monkeypatch.setattr(module_with_code, 'read_from_db', inner)

Also you can mock session's read property with an object with jdbc method, returning a dataframe but it seems much more complicated.
EDIT: I assumed you were using pytest but it seems you use unittest module so in the second scenario you can just
@patch('module_with_test.read_from_db')
def mock_func(session, **kwargs):
    return session.createDataFrame([(1, "Alice"), (2, "Bob")]

